# Listener for Media Player - Android

Tags: android, state, android-mediaplayer, media

I am trying to get the default audio player listener control. Also play/pause etc.

I have created a `BroadcastReceiver` for media. The media player listener not called,

```
<receiver android:name=".MediaStateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I have given the below permissions,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

How can I get the callbacks for audio player controls.

Comment: can you able to post your Receiver implementation too

Comment: @Sree: I have written a BroadcastReceiver class, while change any song or other events, it is not invoking the onReceive function.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private ImageView btnPlay, btnForward, btnBackward, btnNext, btnPrevious;


    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    public static int currentSongIndex = 0;

    private Utilities utils;

    static int count = -1;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player, container, false);

        // All player buttons
        btnPlay = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnForward = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
        btnBackward = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
        btnNext = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnPrevious = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);

        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        utils = new Utilities();

        int position = getArguments().getInt("songIndex");
        currentSongIndex = position;

        playSong(position);


        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.pause();
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                    }
                } else {

                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.start();
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Actually I am looking for the event change in the default audio player.